# does openpublish 7 have menu hook

Tags: drupal, drupal-hooks

have been asked to move a custom made module to another drupal site which is based on openpublish version 7.

but after adding/activating the module , the hook menu does not seem to be working. Just wanted to ask if Openpublish has hooks implemented same as drupal and if not , what alternatives does it have to menu hook (intercept a url and send a reply based on that)..

any help appreciated.

Comment: Hmmph, [Openpublish's documentation](http://products.phase2technology.com/openpublish-d7-documentation) isn't up to much

Comment: @FelixEve Thank you for the comment. have also searched internet and cannot seem to find any answer. thank you again though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue solved after clearing site cache. :)